# Are angular class properties "reactive" by default?

Tags: angular, class, rxjs, properties, reactive

If I have an angular class, e.g:

```
export class ParameterObject {
  _location;
  _searchParameters;
  _selection;
}
```

and I update the properties in some other class or part of my angular code

```
const p = new ParameterObject();
p._location ="Berlin";
```

Will that parameterObject get updated in my other components as well, or will I have to `.next(newValue)` all properties as Observables of some kind?
Because I thought that components is some kind of "singleton" by default if I import it from a central class into other components, or not? so there should be just one updated class throughout my whole app?

Comment: I am afraid I do not fully understand your question but I can tell you that Components are NOT singleton. If you have a Component that represents, for instance, CustomerData and you have a page where you want to show 3 different customers, then you would have 3 different instances of the same Component class. Services, which you share via Dependency Injection, are somehow closer to "singletons". For instance a service which is provided at root level is a singleton. But this is a totally different story from Components.

Comment: ok I understand, I basically want to use the class in a service only and set/get properties via the service onto that class, is that possible or should I use observables only?

Comment: If you want your logic to "react" to changes in the instance held in the service, you have to use Observables (or other similar methods). If you need to fetch the freshest data whenever you want from the service, but NOT REACT to changes, then you do not need Observables.